# Transactions and Order Safety with MySQL (InnoDB)

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

## Scenario

Say I have a list of voucher codes that I am giving away, I need to ensure that if two persons place an order at the exact same time, that they do not get the same voucher.

## Tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `voucher_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `voucher_id` (`voucher_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE `order` ADD CONSTRAINT `order_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`voucher_id`) REFERENCES `voucher` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `voucher` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

## Sample data

```
INSERT INTO `voucher` (`code`) VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C');
```

## Sample Query

```
SELECT @voucher_id := v.id FROM `voucher` v LEFT JOIN `order` o ON o.voucher_id = v.id WHERE o.id IS NULL;
INSERT INTO `order` (`voucher_id`) VALUES (@voucher_id);
```

## Question

I believe the `UNIQUE KEY` on `voucher_id` in the `order` table will prevent two orders having the same `voucher_id`, giving an error / throwing an exception if the same voucher id is inserted twice. This would require a while loop to retry upon failure.
The alternative is read locking the vouchers table before the `SELECT` and releasing that lock after the `INSERT`, ensuring the same voucher isn't picked twice.

My question is therefore:

- Which is faster?

  - A while loop in PHP code.
  - Read locking the vouchers table.
- Is there another way?

#### Edits

`ALTER TABLE`order`CHANGE`voucher_idvoucher_id`BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`
will cause the `INSERT` to fail if `@voucher_id` is null (as desired, as there would be no vouchers left).

Comment: Imagine the voucher table runs out of unused vouchers, you would need to deal with that case. The DB can not solve it for you.

Comment: InnoDB transactions take a snapshot of the data on `BEGIN`, so two of my above selects ran at the same time would produce the same `voucher_id`, failing on the insert.

I just tried this, and the second `INSERT` will wait until the first `COMMIT` and then fail. 

I guess the only way to do it would be to read lock the vouchers table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "correct" and by that I mean best way to do what you're looking to do is to generate the voucher at the time you place the order. Look at the documentation for the sha1() function in php. You can seed it with unique information to prevent duplicates and use that for your voucher along with an auto_increment field for the unique ID.

When the order is placed, PHP generates a new voucher, saves it to the database, and sends it to the user. This way you're only storing valid vouchers and you're also preventing duplicates from being created.

Comment: Unfortunately this was just a hypothetical situation. In the "real world" the voucher codes are from an external source and so can not be generated by myself.

Comment: Ah, in that case you would want to set up a table of the "unused" vouchers using InnoDB (for transactions) and select a voucher from that table at the time of the order, save the voucher to an "active" table for valid vouchers, and delete that record from the other table, finishing the transaction. This will give you separation so that you don't have to worry about wiping out "valid" vouchers when you operate on the 3rd party supply table. The transaction support will lock the record until it is removed so that two people won't get the same voucher.

Comment: Two selects from the "unused" will give the same id though? Is there a way to atomically lock the row the query selects?

Comment: When you call START TRANSACTION; SELECT * FROM `table`; in InnoDB it will lock that table until you finish the transaction with ROLLBACK or COMMIT. So what you're effectively doing is pulling from the InnoDB table to get your record, inserting it into another table. If that insertion completes, you delete the record from the InnoDB table and COMMIT. That prevents someone else from getting the same record from that table as by the time another read is permitted against the table, the record is gone. When you COMMIT it will unlock the table automatically.

Comment: Also, if you want more documentation on exactly how transaction and InnoDB work in MySQL, this is a great resource with examples: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html

Comment: Found it: `SELECT [...] FOR UPDATE`, this will let me use my existing table structure also. It will block the SELECT until other transactions have `COMMIT`ed. Not quite what I wanted, ideally the select would skip over locked rows instead of waiting but I think it works well enough.

Comment: That waiting time will typically be so miniscule that you won't notice the difference anyway :P It will select, update, and unlock very quickly, but since you're only using that code/table when processing a new order, the only time you're even going to notice anything if at all is when two people place and order and click submit at the exact same time. Which is a very tall order in the first place ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8458/discussion-between-brightemo-and-brian)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `START TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT`, and `ROLLBACK` to prevent race conditions in your SQL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/commit.html

In your case, I would just put your transactions into a critical area bounded by these tokens.

Comment: InnoDB transactions take a snapshot of the data on `BEGIN`, so two of my above `SELECT`s ran at the same time would produce the same `voucher_id`, failing on the `INSERT`. This is what happens anyway without the use of transactions because of the `UNIQUE INDEX` on `voucher_id`.

Comment: I am trying to find the fastest way assign a voucher to an order. My two options so far are a while loop, or read locking the table.